# Clicktale integration - trouble with reverse proxy on (on Acquia)

Tags: reverse-proxy, varnish, acquia, clicktale

We are trying to incorporate ClickTale for our site which is hosted on Acquia. But there seems to be a problem and we would like to hear from people over here if they have come across a similar situation.

1. We already have HTTPS enabled.
2. Because of HTTPS, we had to change
   our DNS setting from an A record to a CNAME record.
3. Now based on
   this ClickTale Wiki -
   http://wiki.clicktale.com/Article/Help_talk:Drupal_integration_module_v1...
   whenever we have a reverse proxy, we need to make sure that the IP
   address of the proxy is allowed which would mean ClickTale servers
   be able to identify the IP address of the end user.
4. Because we have a CNAME record, we have a canonical URL but we dont have an IP.

How do we deal with this situation? If we do not do anything, will Acquia servers ensure that the right headers are in place such that ClickTale servers could read end users IP?

Answer (score 0):

As per Acquia documentation they use the X-forwarded-for header to forward you the client IP, see https://docs.acquia.com/articles/logging-client-ip-apache-behind-reverse-proxy

So from the doc you quote yourself, i would enable the following:

> If your proxy includes the original IP address in the HTTP headers, you could add a module setting in your config.php file to instruct the module to use that header. If your proxy uses a header field called "X-Forwarded-For" (this is common), then add   $config['IPAddressHeaderFieldName'] = "X-Forwarded-For";   to your config.php file to utilize this field.